# Register Delta table in Hive metastore error

Tags: hive, pyspark, amazon-emr, delta-lake

I need to register Delta table in Hive metastore to be able to query it using external reporting tool connecting to ThriftServer

PySpark API works well, I am able to create DeltaTable object

```
ordersDeltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_path)
```

When I am running SQL command

```
%%sql
CREATE TABLE orders_delta
USING DELTA
LOCATION '/tmp/orders/delta/'
```

or

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE orders_delta USING delta LOCATION '/tmp/orders/delta/'")
```

or this one

```
%%sql
CREATE TABLE orders_delta
USING delta
AS SELECT *
FROM csv.`s3://orders/raw/public/order_items/`
```

I always have the same exception

```
An error was encountered:
u'Can not create a Path from an empty string'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", 
line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7- 
   src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", 
line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
IllegalArgumentException: u'Can not create a Path from an empty 
string'
```

I am using

EMR 5.27.0
Spark 2.4.4
Hive 2.3.5 
delta-core_2.11-0.4.0.jar
with Jupyter Notebook.

Is there any other way to regiser DeltaTable in Hive metastore?

Comment: I found it is an open issue https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/177. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as of Delta Lake 0.4.0, while it includes the PySpark API as noted [Simple, Reliable Upserts and Deletes on Delta Lake Tables using Python APIs](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/10/03/simple-reliable-upserts-and-deletes-on-delta-lake-tables-using-python-apis.html), SQL DML is not supported yet.  The error message is due to the Spark SQL DML to create the table but it isn't supported for Delta Lake yet; it is in the Delta Lake future roadmap.

Due to this and some other issues, Delta Lake 0.4.0 does not support Hive metastore tables yet; this is also in the Delta Lake future roadmap as well.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response. Is there any timeline estimation for the Hive metastore feature delivery in open source version?

Comment: While it is being worked on for the near term, I don't have a timeline estimate yet as there are multiple moving parts involved.  As soon as we have one, it'll be added to https://github.com/delta-io/delta/milestones.

Comment: thank you for the info. Without a timeline and a workaround I am going to try an alternative library Hudi https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/support-record-level-insert-update-and-delete-on-amazon-s3-with-amazon-emr/

Answer (score 1):

Any strong reason to go via hive. when u bringup emr u can enable glue catalog. So the tables created by spark directly syncup with glue. Then u can use external users connect to athena for their reports --essentially u can get rid of hive and ever running EMR ths way.

Alternate to athena is redshift spectrum

Comment: Exactly, the tables created by Spark. My point is table creating by Spark using Delta does not work.

Comment: oh! nice to know